# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::exchanges()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

> **ERROR:** BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2435:
>   *Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::exchanges()*

There are two tables, named as EXCHANGES table and FINALTRADES table.

Exchanges table has START_TIME field (with format : 00:00:00) and **finaltrades table has exchange_id**.

I want to count entries only which come between start_time to start_time+1hrs from final trades table. FOR EXAMPLE: If start_time has 09:15:00, then count between 09:15:00 to 10:15:00 records only.

Function:

```js
public function getCountHour() {
       $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $countTrades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
            ->exchanges()
            ->where('start_time', '>=', $your_desired_time)
            ->where('start_time' , '<=' , strtotime($your_desired_time) + 60*60)
            ->count();

                return response()->json($countTrades);

    }
```

Relationship given to FnalTrade model:

```
   public function exchanges(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\EXCHANGE_MODEL_NAME', 'id', 'exchange_id');
}
```

[both table SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFu7d.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
$countTrades = FinalTrade::whereUserId(Auth::id())
  ->whereHas('exchanges', function($query) use ($your_desired_time) {
    $query
      ->where('start_time', '>=', $your_desired_time)
      ->where('start_time' , '<=' , strtotime($your_desired_time) + 60*60);
})
->count();
```

Comment: I want to count the entries between time from finaltrades table. Let me try your code.

Comment: Ok, now I’m lost. What exactly are trying to calculate? Final trades from exchanges with given start times? If so, I’ll need to update the answer

Comment: its clear, i want to count entries of finaltrades table, and finaltrades table has exchange_id because, exchanges table has time. herein, i wanted to count only entries between the time. @ jedrzej.kuryl

Comment: I wanted to count columns from finaltables..but in the exchanges table has start_time which decide range of time for counting.  that means, you can check the table exchange table has ID-1 and and start_time, 09:15:00 then.. for first hour 09:15:00 to 10:15:00 (this is first hour)... now count the entry of finaltrades table between this time.